# Which way to return value works faster in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Lets suppose that some function has multiple `if` statemens, like in the code below.
Is there any difference in these two ways of returning some default value? Can anyone tell me about pos and cons of these two approaches?

First:

```
CustomClass foo(const Param* par)
{
    if (nullptr == par)
        return CustomClass();

    if (!check1(par))
        return CustomClass();

    if (!check2(par))
        return CustomClass();

    // some code

    return CustomClass();
}
```

Second:

```
CustomClass foo(const Param* par)
{
    CustomClass ret;
    if (nullptr == par)
        return ret;

    if (!check1(par))
        return ret;

    if (!check2(par))
        return ret;

    // some code

    return ret;
}
```

Seems it should depends on copiler...

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking and/or looking at the generated assembly?

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if a compiler would generate different code for this two snippets

Comment: why do you think this should make any difference

Comment: Somewhere I read something like: _do not do the job of the compiler_, but where was that...

Comment: Even if these are somehow going to produce different code (I really doubt that, and you shouldn't rely on such things, because they are extremely compiler-related), I think, calling pretty much ANY constructor, allocating memory, etc, will have a lot bigger effect on the performance than this branching.

Comment: Just do this: `auto foo( const Param* ) -> CustomClass { return {}; }`. Assuming the checks don't have side effects.

Comment: [Which is faster? Eric Lippert's Performance Rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Returning the same variable vs different ones may affect if compiler will do or not NRVO optimization. But that is compiler dependent.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKtHxKJRwp4

Comment: @Filburt An excellent rant, especially #2.

Comment: Write correct readable code first, then if you have a performance issue you've discovered by profiling that code, optimize that performance issue. If this function is the slowest part of your code it is because of what those check functions do, not because of how you return the variable.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: I disagree, almost the whole rant is wrong. When there are multiple solutions to a problem, and someone wants to make a habit to choose the better solution, then it is absolutely valid to put the question about performance. Like this one. If we go back in time, these two solutions could have a performance difference, because compilers weren't smart enough. And it is just a habit to use the better one. Even if it is not the bottleneck, and even if it doesn't make too much difference. Why not choose the better solution (even if it is just 1% better), if it takes nothing to do so?

Comment: The first one is a candidate for *guaranteed* `RVO` (optimization) but mainstream compilers will likely optimize both the same.

Comment: @geza look at the i++ vs ++i in a for loop.  In the early days, it made a difference in the assembler.  Now it doesn't.  Was it ever worth discussing, given that the payback is going to be, on average, vastly less than 1%?  I disagree with the rant, but I also disagree that performance issues should be approached in any way other than with a profiler; because that will always highlight to you where your greatest gains are for your time.

Comment: Your example will collapse to the return value only, as all the ifs are leading to the same result. So it is no good for testing. In general it will be dificult to state what a compiler will do in a certain situation. **Always benchmark**... it is that simple. The only thing you can say is, that from `C++17` on the first case will be guaranteed copy-ellision, the second may be if the compiler chooses.

Comment: @UKMonkey: In my opinion, it is worth discussing. It shouldn't be considered very hard, but if we can phrase certain rules, then it is not hard to follow. For example, for your example: if `++i` was better back then, then one should stick with it, even if it is just 1%. Why not? It has the same complexity as `i++`, it takes nothing to write `++i` instead of `i++`. Sure, these rules can change, and sometimes should be revised. This is not optimization, but avoiding "pessimization". And yes, finding bottlenecks should be done with a profiler, of course. But it is a different matter.

Comment: @geza "Why not?" because the cost of even just discussing it outweighs the gains.  Your 1% is a massive over estimate on the return; and if there's a 10% gain to be had after 2 hours of profiling and editing from 1 person, rather than a 0.01% gain after 20 minutes discussion between 2 people; the cost of the gain is just excessive. It makes for an interesting discussion in principle - sure; but when looking at real code, these questions are best avoided

Comment: @UKMonkey: okay, we must work in a different field of IT. Optimizing unoptimized code is easy. So your example of 10% gain in 2 hours is only true at the beginning. There can be a case, when you have to squeeze out everything what's possible. Then it is not acceptable to write suboptimal code in the first place. Writing RVO optimizable code was important back then, it could easily caused much more than 1% performance loss (hint: a lot of unnecessary copies, even allocating ones).

Comment: @geza I think you missed the point of the rant. People should absolutely choose more efficient algorithms and containers when they are writing code, but to agonize over whether one or the other examples above are faster is silly. It just doesn't matter unless you can prove it matters by profiling, and having established a baseline, determine if you have in fact made code faster or slower. I use ++i because I know it is not worse than i++, but I'd much rather write clean maintainable code while not worrying about things that will not matter.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: You might missed the point of my comments too :) How do you know which things matter? How do you know which things **may** matter in certain situations? Profiling is a way. Other way is to ask. Maybe other people are more experienced than you, and can tell you the answer. If you don't know whether `i++` or `++i` better, then you can ask it. Or measure, but measuring such things are hard, needs expertise, you need to try these kind of things out in certain situations. Btw, "++i because I know it is not worse than i++", is exactly my point, and isn't in agreement with the rant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are subjects for compiler optimisation. First one is URVO (unnamed return value optimisation), second - NRVO (named return value optimisation). The C++ standard explicitly allows compilers to elude copying.

> [12.8]
>
> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to
>   omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the
>   constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor
>   for the object have side effects.
>
> ...in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object
>   (other than a function parameter ...) with the same type (ignoring
>   cv-qualification) as the function return type, the copy/move operation
>   can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the
>   function call’s return object

Modern versions of GCC, Clang, and MSVC would yield equal assembly for both cases even with no optimisations enabled. Here are some examples:

- [URVO](https://godbolt.org/g/rRPa6C)
- [NRVO](https://godbolt.org/g/tMNxtg)

Comment: From `C++17` the first option will be a candidate for guaranteed `RVO`.

Comment: In your URVO example the MSVC is ignoring switches

Comment: The other as well.

Answer (score 3):

Any sensible compiler *should* produce the same code for the two functions, because they mean exactly the same thing and the optimiser can deduce this fact relatively easily.

Remember, your source code is not a one-to-one mapping of CPU instructions: it is *a description of a program*. It is your compiler's job to take this description and produce the best "actual" code that performs the same function, and your compiler is very good at doing so! My point being that the actual compiled code will look almost nothing like either function anyway.

Ultimately, though, whether this is truly the case on your particular platform and using your particular implementation, can only be determined by actually examining the resulting assembly code. If all you care about is performance you could draw the line at benchmarking it.